# how do I best/easiest index my matlab (.m) files?

Tags: matlab, indexing, google-desktop-search

I need to search a large set of matlab (.m) files, and I can't find a way to do it in Google Desktop. I haven't seen any source code indexer that supports matlab either.

What options do I have?

Comment: What are you searching for?  Using regular expressions or straight text?  In a certain directory or many?  Across a network or local?

Comment: Locally on HD, straight text in many directories.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest checking out a submission from [Urs Schwarz](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/4309) on [The MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/):

- [grep: a pedestrian, very fast grep utility](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9647)

This should allow you to search through a series of files or folders from within MATLAB.

---

**Previous answer:**

If you are simply trying to *locate* m-files, but not search *within* them, then the following may help...

Assuming all of the m-files you want to search through are on the [MATLAB path](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/path.html) (which they would pretty much have to be if you actually want to *run* them in MATLAB), then you can use the [WHICH](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/which.html) function to find where they are located.

For example, if I wanted to find all the overloaded functions with the name "display", I could do this:

```
>> which display -all
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009a\toolbox\matlab\lang\@cell\display)             % cell method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009a\toolbox\matlab\lang\@double\display)           % double method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009a\toolbox\matlab\lang\@logical\display)          % logical method
built-in (C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2009a\toolbox\matlab\lang\@char\display)
...
```

You can also use the functional form of WHICH to collect the file paths in a cell array:

```
filePaths = which('display','-all');
```

Comment: well, Google Desktop can locate the files for me , what I want is a fast way to search in the actual code..

Comment: @Fredriku73: Fair enough. I found another option and will edit my answer to include it shortly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Larry's Any Text File Indexer](http://desktop.google.com/plugins/i/indexitall.html) to get Google Desktop to index MATLAB files.  Just install the plug-in and specify ".m" as the extension of interest.

Answer (score 0):

Grep would be a good tool:

$ grep *pattern* path

or

$ grep *pattern* -ri path

for a case insensitive, recursive search

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of matlab this has become somewhat easier.

In the `Home` menu select: `Find Files`

There you have the option to search for files containing certain text.